# How to click on a Cell object?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using Javascript, p5.js, and Daniel Shiffman's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKYlikFAV4k&t=2437s) to create a visual representation of an A* search algorithm.

An image of an example grid looks like this:
 [example grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fb49.png)

Is it possible to click on any cell of the grid, in order to print out it's attributes? Based on Daniel Shiffman's other tutorial on [how to click on objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEHsr4XicN8), I understand I have to create 2 functions that activate and execute respectively. I understand how to do this with a circle because a circle has a radius.

But, I don't understand how to do this with a cell because I only have it's coordinates. I can't see how to use coordinates as a metric to calculate length.

I'd appreciate any guidance to my thinking. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: See the `collidePointRect()` method in the `p5.collide2D
` library (https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D#collidepointrect). You should pass the mouse coords along with the position and dimensions you use for the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial on collision detection available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection). That's for regular Processing, but everything is the same in P5.js. You're looking for rectangle-point collision.

Basically, you need to check whether the point is between the left and right edges of the rectangle **and** between the top and bottom edges of the rectangle. If both are true, then the point is inside the rectangle.

I recommend [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking those steps on one at a time. For example, try getting it working with a single hard-coded rectangle and point before you try it with multiple cells or with user input.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It works, but not with 100% accuracy. The squares I am trying to click on are very small. Do you think the smallness has something to do with inaccuracy? Please check the image I uploaded as reference.

Comment: @elbertkim No, the size of the squares should not matter, as long as you can get the mouse inside them. If you have a follow-up question, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question post. Good luck.